How to create a dashboard filter that works as case owner for case report type and created by for email report type
Same as the title.
I want to create a dashboard filter that works as "Case Owner" filter for case reports (based on case custom report type) and "Created by" filter for email reports (report is using email custom report type). I tried creating few dashboard but every time I select "Case Owner: Full Name" from case report type as filter it auto assign the "Parent Case: Case Owner: Full Name" filter for reports based on email report type and I can't edit it. If I use "Created By: Full Name" filter from email report type then I can use "Assigned To: Full Name" in reports based on case report type but in our org we are not populating "Assigned To" field, we are only populating "Case Owner" field when owner of case changes.
